# How I can get a signal when GC starts running?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I'm developing C# .NET script and I want to know if during a method executing the Garbage Collector was called or not like handling a signal ?

I want to be sure that the time delay was caused by the GC .

Comment: GC run on separate Thread, Thread number 2

Comment: You might want to look into using [GC.TryStartNoGCRegion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906201(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, when the GC is running, all your threads are suspended. So you can't do anything in managed code while GC is running.

There's a lot of options to get some kind of notification, though. For example, you could have a thread that does

```
var status = GC.WaitForFullGCApproach();
```

Note that you also have to use `GC.RegisterForFullGCNotification` to make this work. And of course, it has its own performance cost etc. Tweaking anything with how GC works is generally a bad idea.

If you want to find if there was a collection while some code run, you can use `GC.CollectionCount` before and after, and see if it changed.

Comment: Your program might be frozen, but you can still receive the notification a few milliseconds later to log.

Comment: @Blindy Yup, that's why I've shown two ways to do this :)